# Are irrational numbers like π relationships which are established by some rule or criteria?

Tags: definition, irrational-numbers, pi, constants

[Rational and Irrational of Reals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAuWr.jpg)

Irrational numbers appear to fill in the ‘gaps’ between Rational numbers on a Real number line. However they seem to be stipulations or definitions of relationships which are established by some rule or criteria.

Take π, for an example: There is no precise definition of what it means. This fact becomes evident over the entire known history of this ‘number’ (relationship). It’s not the computation that is the problem; rather, the *definition of its meaning*.

Is π in this formula:
$area=πr^2$

[π as an area component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJf1i.png)

the same as π in this formula:
$C = 2\pi r$

[π as an arc component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvrD7.gif)

They are stipulated or defined to be the same, but are they not *acting* as two completely different *constants of proportionality*?

Comment: Not all irrational numbers fulfill some relation or criteria (assuming you mean "criteria" as something identifying a single, unique irrational number). In fact, most of them don't, but we can't give you any concrete examples, because that would be a criteria that identified one of them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number stipulates them to be "In mathematics, the irrational numbers are all the real numbers which are not rational numbers,..."

Comment: "There is no precise definition of what it means" Sure there is. On p. 302 of Calculus by Spivak, $\pi$ is defined to be $2 \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1 - x^2} \, dx$. Other authors might start with a different definition of $\pi$, but we can prove that the various definitions of $\pi$ are equivalent. "They are stipulated or defined to be the same" They are *proved* to be the same, if you read the right books.

Comment: $\pi $ is a *number*. Not an area. Not an arc. It is dimensionless, the dimension comes from $r$ (in your examples). It is a known number that just doesn't happen to be a ratio of two integers. There are many formulas that let you calculate it to an arbitrary number of decimals. It does appear in a lot of places in the mathematics, but this is not a wonder; it is more that *we* (humans) recognised *a* number that often pops up and gave it a name $\pi$.

Comment: I changed the "area" and "arc", to which you refer, to "area component" and "arc component" to more clearly reflect my meaning.

Answer (score 3):

There are uncountably many numbers on the real line. Most of them are just there and serve as a sort of "glue" in order to make the system ${\mathbb R}$ complete. The real numbers that actually do occur in mathematics as individuals of interest  are all defined by criteria, formulas, or algorithmic procedures, etc.

The irrational number $\sqrt{2}$ is the unique positive real number whose square is $=2$. The number $e$ is defined, e.g., as limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n\ .$$
For highschool purposes $\pi$ is defined as ratio circumference/diameter of arbitrary circles; but of course at a higher level we could define $\pi$ by
$$\pi=4\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\>dx$$
without reference to folklore facts of elementary geometry.

Answer (score 1):

> **Two hints:**
>
> - Irrational numbers can be built from the rational numbers and then identified with specific *[Dedekind cuts](https://brilliant.org/wiki/dedekind-cuts/)* or with specific equivalence classes of *[Cauchy-sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_Cauchy_sequences)*.
>
>   This way we see an intimate relationship of the irrational numbers with the rational numbers based upon two construction principles.
> - The book *[Mathematical constants](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521818052)* by Steven R. Finch provides a thorough guided tour about *named* mathematical constants, many of them being irrational numbers.
>
>   Going through this book and looking for connections and different relationships
>     might be fruitful and interesting.